# killing/stopping Jenkins job with a very long list

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm new to Jenkins so I hope my terms are correct:

I have a Jenkins job that triggers another job. This second job tests a very long list of items (maybe 2000) it gets from the trigger.

Because it's such a long list, I pass it to the second job in groups of 20.

Unfortunately, this list turned out to take an extremely long time, and I can't stop it.
No matter what I tried, stop/kill only stop the **current group of 20**, and proceeds to the group.
Waiting for it to finish, or doing this manually for each group is not an option.

I guess the entire list was already passed to the second job, and it's loading the next group whenever the current one ends.

What I tried:

- Clicking the "stop" button next to the build on the trigger and the second job
- Using purge build queue add on
- Using the following script in script console:

  ```
  def jobname = "Trigger Job"
  def buildnum = 123
  def job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobname)
   for (build in job.builds) {
       if (buildnum == build.getNumber().toInteger()){
         if (build.isBuilding()){
           build.doStop();
           build.doKill();
         }
       }
  }
  ```
- Using the following script in script console:

  ````
  String job = 'Job name';
  List<Integer> build_list = [];
  def result = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem(job).getBuilds().findAll{
  it.isBuilding() == true && (!build_list || build_list.contains(it.id.toInteger()))}.each{it.doStop()}.collect{it.id};
  println new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(result).toPrettyString(); ```
  ````

This is my groovy part of the code that splits it into groups of 20. Maybe I should put the parallel part outside the sub list loop?
Is there a better way to divide into sub lists for future use?

```
stages {
        stage('Execute tests') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Limit number of items to run
                    def shortList = IDs.take(IDs.size()) // For testing purpose, can be removed if not needed
                    println(Arrays.toString(shortList))
                    
                    // devide the list of items into small, equal,sub-lists
                    def colList = shortList.toList().collate(20)
                    for (subList in colList) {
                        testStepsForParallel = subList.collectEntries {
                            ["Testing on ${it}": {
                                catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                    stage(it) {
                                        def buildWrapper = build job: "Job name",
                                                parameters: [
                                                        string(name: 'param1', value: it.trim()),
                                                        string(name: 'param2', value: "")
                                                ],
                                                propagate: false
                                        remoteBuildResult = buildWrapper.result
                                        println("Remote build results: ${remoteBuildResult}")
                                        if (remoteBuildResult == "FAILURE") {
                                            currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                                        }
                                        catchError(stageResult: 'UNSTABLE') {
                                            copyArtifacts projectName: "Job name", selector: specific("${buildWrapper.number}")
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                        parallel testStepsForParallel
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Don't know what else to do to stop this run.

Comment: Are all these batches of tests queued up or all running in parallel? If queued, first kill the feeder job, then clear the queue (`Jenkins.instance.queue.clear()`), then kill then the running jobs, .

Comment: @IanW Thanks. The feeder (trigger) job was already killed but the second one keeps going. I'm not sure how to tell if they're queued. I can say that the large list was given on the step I attached and from that I'm (think) building smaller jobs in a loop (of groups of 20)

Comment: Reger to [Jenkins Queue javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Queue.html) and query.